# How can I create multiple arrays from lines out of a file?

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
with open('filename') as f:
    list1 = f.read().splitlines()
    print list1
```

This gives me a comma-separated list with each line from the file like this:
['line1', 'line2', 'line3',...]

I now want to separate each line into it's own array like so: [ [line1], [line2], [line3]...] -How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `list` within a list comprehension

```
with open('filename') as f:
    list1 = [[i] for i in f.read().splitlines()]
    print list1
```

Comment: to remove the quotes on each line is split a viable option?

Comment: @DylanM: What do you mean " remove the quotes"? The quotes signify that the element of the inner list is a string.

Comment: @DylanM: _Maybe_ you want this? `print '[' + ', '.join(['[{0}]'.format(s) for s in f.read().splitlines()]) + ']'`

Comment: the file i am using is a bunch of data I want to later use to create a matrix. wouldn't this create a problem having quotes in each array?

Comment: @DylanM: If this is supposed to be an array of numbers then you'll have to convert those strings you read from the file into numbers, using the `int()` or `float()` functions. Otherwise you won't be able to do arithmetic with them.

Comment: what you posted is what I think I will need. thank you so much!

Comment: @DylanM: It will be easier for people to give you an appropriate answer if you add some sample data to the question, and what the resulting data structure (eg a list of lists) from that data should look like.

Comment: @DylanM: That code I posted above is useful if you want your script to read the numbers from a file & then print out a list of lists that you can paste into another script. But it's **not** the way to do it if you want to do the matrix arithmetic in the same script that reads the numbers from the file.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is pull data from http://sirius.chem.vt.edu/~crawdad/programming/project3/h2o_sto3g/t.dat and create a matrix out of it. The first column specifies the row and the second column specifies the column number. The 3rd column in the file is the data that I want the matrix to contain. I'm trying to understand how I can create a script that will recognize that the first two columns are the location that I want the 3rd column to be placed.